# Cakephp3 doesn't recognize the table with different name in deep associations

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.7

I have created a table called `Delegates`, and I created a UsersTable and User Entity. And I have used `$this->setTable('delegates');`  in `UsersTable` to be able to access Delegates from `$this->Users;` (I just want to say I have created a User Model with delegates table)

So far so good...

In my application I am trying to access deep associations. Every thing is fine with this query but when I `contain` the `User` model I get `The Users association is not defined on Comments.`

I can confirm the associations are set correctly.

```
...
// There are more associations up there. 
...
'Comments', [
        'className' => 'App\Model\Table\CommentsTable',
        'foreignKey' => 'delegate_assessment_criteria_id',
        'belongsTo' => [
            'Assessors' => [
                'className' => 'App\Model\Table\AssessorsTable',
                'foreignKey' => 'assessor_id',
            ],
            'Users' => [
                'className' => 'App\Model\Table\UsersTable',
                'foreignKey' => 'delegate_id',
            ]
        ]
    ]
```

Here is deep association.

```
...
// There are more associations up there. 
...
'Comments' => function($q) {
    return $q
        ->select([
            'id'
        ])
        ->order(['Comments.created DESC'])  
        ->contain([
            'Assessors' => function($q) {
                return $q
                    ->select([
                        'id'
                    ])
                    ->enableAutoFields();
            }
        ])   
        ->contain([                                                                           
            'Users' => function($q) {
                return $q
                    ->select([
                        'id',
                        'delegate_id'
                    ])
                    ->enableAutoFields();
            }
        ])   
        ->enableAutoFields();
}
```

**2 Notes:**

- If I contain the `User` model in very first in hierarchy of my query I
  can access the `User` fields but in deep association this doesn't
  work.
- If I contain `Delegates` it works.

I believe there is a problem with Cakephp query builder.

Comment: Your first block of code, where you define the Comments association, where is this? Because it looks like you're trying to define the Users association inside another association, which is not at all how it works. Rather, the association of Users with Comments must happen inside the Comments model, so that *anything* that is associated with Comments gets that next level, and you don't have to re-define it for every model that's associated with Comments. Hope that's clear.

Comment: @GregSchmidt Thank you but this is just to give an idea to the reader what is the structure of my Table Models. and as I mentioned I have 2 tables `Users` and `Delegates`. I want to use `delegates` as `Users`. All the associations has been setup in (`Table Models`). Please read the question again. I believe there is problem with deep ORM associations.

Comment: Many people, myself included, are using deep associations on a daily basis. So I believe there's something wrong with your code. If you show us more of your initialize function, we may be able to give more concrete suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright finally I figured it out. I have done it before I don't know why I forgot. Probably because I was in deep association I drained into it.

The deep association contain was creating conflict with very first contain. if I would set different `propertyName` in deep associations then it does the purpose.

**Bear in mind you must set this associations on your Table Models.**

```
'Comments', [
        'className' => 'App\Model\Table\CommentsTable',
        'foreignKey' => 'delegate_assessment_criteria_id',
        'belongsTo' => [
            'Assessors' => [
                'className' => 'App\Model\Table\AssessorsTable',
                'foreignKey' => 'assessor_id',
            ],
            'Delegates' => [   //  <= Here set the name of Assossiation you want to be shown in array
                'className' => 'App\Model\Table\UsersTable',
                'propertyName' => 'delegates',   // <=  Add propertyName and set another name here
                'foreignKey' => 'delegate_id',
            ]
        ]
    ]
```

And on association

```
'Comments' => function($q) {
    return $q
        ->select([
            'id'
        ])
        ->order(['Comments.created DESC'])  
        ->contain([
            'Assessors' => function($q) {
                return $q
                    ->select([
                        'id'
                    ])
                    ->enableAutoFields();
            }
        ])   
        ->contain([                                                                           
            'Users' => function($q) {
                return $q
                    ->select([
                        'id',
                        // 'delegate_id'  // <= Remove this - We have already done it when we set the association on above code.
                    ])
                    ->enableAutoFields();
            }
        ])   
        ->enableAutoFields();
}
```